# New flutter project with new AGP and Gradle version

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I wanna start a new flutter project without change AGP version and Gradle version manually before running first time on emulator, flutter doctor output :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19043.1466], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Error log :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'F:\flutterdev\Personal\untitled1\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist
```

If I change AGP (android/build.gradle) classpath from 4.1.0 to 4.0.2 and gradle wrapper (android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) url from 6.7-all to  6.4.1-all it works, but this is a workaround, not a solution, so I wanna change the source where flutter create get AGP and Gradle information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Flutter and from today I have the same problem and like you I have changed the URL but not to 6.4.1-all, I have changed in 7.4-all, the lastest version currently available at https://services.gradle.org/distributions/.

I still have these warnings:

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
```

but VS Code and Android Studio build in debug mode correctly.

Comment: What version of the gradle plugin (folder android, file build.gradle) did you use ?

Comment: Actually I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' but by default vs-code put 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'